# Access virtual machine from browser under virtual box

Tags: networking, 20.04

I am running on 20.04.1. I have a virtual machine installed using Oracle VirtualBox 6.12. The VM is also Ubuntu 20.04. The virtual machine networking type is `bridged`. When I try to access the virtual machine from Google Chrome or from Firefox on the host, I get a report of `connection refused` on the virtual machine, I can use ping on the VM to access both `localhost` and the IP address. nmap on the VM can acesss `localhost` successfully but not the IP address of the VM. Neither `ping` nor `nmap` can access `localhost` or the IP address of the VM when used from the host. Both machines are on the same subnet. I have tried with `ufw` both enabled and disabled on the VM. This has worked before for me using the same host but a different VM. In addition, I cannot use `ssh` on port 22 from the host to the VM with the same problem.

I tried making a new virtual machine which changed the problem slightly. In this case, I was still unable to connect to a web server on the VM through a browser on my host but I was able to ping the VM from the host. `nmap` on the host still stated that it thought that the VM was down.

Any ideas on how I can troubleshoot this?

Comment: I don't quite get "*I am able to ping [...] the network address of the VM.*" and "*I am unable to ping the VM from the host machine*." Those seem contradictory as written, so please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1276170/edit) to clarify a bit, please..

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to enable port-forwarding on the VM. (with the `NAT` type in the `Attached to` option)

In Virtualbox, choose the `Settings` of the context menu of the VM (or `Machine -> Settings` while the VM is running), go to `Network`, then expand the `Advanced` option and choose `Port Forwarding`. In the dialogbox that shows up, click the `+` sign to add a new TCP/IP rule (if not exists).

In both the `Host Port` and `Guest Port` fields, enter a port number (e.g. `8080`), then click `OK`.

Now, you should be able to access the servers (e.g. HTTP on `8080`) on the guest (if you have configured an HTTP server at that port).

Comment: Two points.
1. I have never needed to use port forwarding in the past.
1. Ping and nmap should be able to find the address of the VM and work with it. The problem seems to be at the hardware address level, rather than at the port level.

Comment: Also I need `bridged` networking for other reasons, so NAT addressing is not usable.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem had nothing to do with the operating system. The web server was coming up on `127.0.0.1` which was not accessible on the network. Changing it to come up on `0.0.0.0` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This was also driving me nuts for a while.  I have a LAMP stack running on Alma linux - running in virtualbox - network settings bridged mode.  On the lamp server vm itself, I could bring up a browser and put in http://server-IP and it works no problem.  I then powered up a cloned alma linux also in bridged mode.  I could PING the lamp server with the clone but when I put the IP address in a browser, I could not connect.  I also have a windows 10 host.  I tried in the browser to resolve the lamp IP and this also failed.  So I shut down both vms last night and called it quits.  Today I fired them up, got on the win10 host, and could not resolve the page on the lamp vm again.  THEN - I tried http://server-IP:8080 - this failed.  Then I tried http://server-IP:80 and... it worked!  It works on the other vm now but I did NOT have to put the port 80 in, despite the fact that I couldn't resolve the site on this vm yesterday.  So in bridged mode, with promiscuous mode set to deny, I can resolve a website by just putting that 80 port number in the URL.  Fwiw